# How to get information from the same column java and sql

Tags: java, sql, swing

So I'm trying to create an application and for my login I have users enter only a pin. I want to open up a new JFrame depending on their Job title. in my database, I have made a column in my users table called 'occupation'. How do I get the information in that column in order to create different IF Statements depending their job title?

```
     try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurantdb", "root","");
            String sql = "Select * from users where pin=?";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, PinField.getText());
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Succesful");
                /*if (occupation = "Server") {

                New ServerWindow
                }
                */
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed");
                PinField.setText("");

            }
            con.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Preparedstatement job=con.prepareStatement("SELECT 
Occupation FROM USERS WHERE PIN=?"); 
job.setString(1,PinField.getText());

try(ResultSet myJob=job.executeQuery())
{
 if(myJob.next())
 {
  String theJob=myJob.getString("Occupation");

  if(theJob.equals("Whatever u want");{/*open frame 1*/}
  if(theJob.equals("Whatever u want 2");{/*open frame 2*/}
 }
}
```

OR

Since u already have the full data in ResultSet rs do this

```
  String theJob=rs.getString("Occupation");

  if(theJob.equals("Whatever u want");{/*open frame 1*/}
  if(theJob.equals("Whatever u want 2");{/*open frame 2*/}
```